# create function that returns date table in mysql phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Can I create a function in my database with the following query?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION DateBackbone(@StartDate Datetime,  @EndDate DateTime )    
    RETURNS  TABLE @Dates  (  Date DateTime  )  AS  
    BEGIN  
        While @StartDate <= @EndDate  
        begin  
            insert @Dates (Date) Values (@StartDate)  
            Set @StartDate = @StartDate + 1  
        end  
        RETURN  
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I do not see a query here. There is only a function.

Comment: Yes it's only function, I want to change this function to using in my Mysql database

Comment: Hi, I don't think we understand your question. Have you tried to create this function, and if so is there an error message you get?